# Can you change the initial sort direction of a column in an auto-sorting DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

We have a DataGrid which displays a column of read-only checkboxes, bound to a property in our ViewModel.  We enabled sorting in the DataGrid and it works as expected; when you click a column's header and it sorts on that column.  Click it again, and the sort is reversed, toggling each time the user clicks that same column.

The issue we're having is when a user clicks on the checkbox column, the initial sort order is Ascending which puts all the unchecked rows first whereas we want all the checked rows first.  In other words, we want the initial sort order (i.e. when you first click that column) to be Descending, not Ascending.

Note: This is purely in the UI, and specifically within the DataGrid itself. It is not part of the ViewModel, so we can't change anything there.

So how can you change a column's initial sort direction?

Answer (score 0):

By using a CollectionView with the DataGrid you can implement custom sorting. This would allow you to specify the default sorting that you require without having to play with inverse property values. Here's a link to some basic examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I understand that you can do that, but that doesn't address this issue I'm asking about, which is the sorting that's applied with the DataGrid which changes the sort when you click on the headers.  For instance, I want them to click on the Name column to sort on that, but then click on the IsSelected column and sort on that.  I just want the initial sort direction for that column to be the reverse. Make sense?